# Ant design 4 expiry date shoud not be less than issue date

Tags: antd

I am new to ant design. I have a form with two date pickers. Issue date and expiry date. I want to be able to limit the date picker for the expiry date to not be earlier than the issue date. This is my approach so far.

```
 <Form.Item
                      label="Issue Date"
                      name={["userIdentification", "identification_issue_date"]}
                      rules={[
                        {
                          required: true,
                          message: REQUIRED_ERROR_MESSAGE,
                        },
                      ]}
                    >
                      <DatePicker
                        disabledDate={(current) =>
                          current && current > moment()
                        }
                      />
                    </Form.Item>

                    <Form.Item
                      label="Expiry Date"
                      name={[
                        "userIdentification",
                        "identification_expiry_date",
                      ]}
                      dependencies={[
                        "userIdentification",
                        "identification_issue_date",
                      ]}
                      rules={[
                        {
                          required: true,
                          message: REQUIRED_ERROR_MESSAGE,
                        },
                        ({ getFieldValue }) => ({
                          validator(_, value) {
                            console.log(
                              "fields value from issue_date",
                              getFieldValue([
                                "userIdentification",
                                "identification_issue_date",
                              ])
                            );
                            if (!value && getFieldValue("allocation") === "") {
                              return Promise.reject(REQUIRED_ERROR_MESSAGE);
                            }
                            return Promise.resolve();
                          },
                        }),
                      ]}
                    >
                      <DatePicker
                        disabledDate={(current) =>
                          current && current > moment()
                        }
                      />
                    </Form.Item>
```

Any help would be greatly appreaciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can read on [this](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/5146) forum 
the best solution found is to use disableDate
and add this code

```
<DatePicker value={value} onChange={this.onDatePickerChange} disabledDate={d => !d || d.isBefore(minimum)} />
```

Another way to do that could be adding something like a minDate with a similar process as above. You can read more [here](https://ant.design/components/date-picker/#components-date-picker-demo-disabled-date)

Comment: I understand this. But I want to be able to pass the value of the issue date field as the mimiumu value in the DatePicker